# How can I use PowerMock to mock final classes in an SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt, powermock

PowerMock doesn't have ScalaTest support, so I'm trying to use JUnit to run my ScalaTest classes, using `@RunWith[classOf[JUnitRunner]]`. Using Maven, you can configure the javaagent module to eagerly load to support this, as detailed in [the PowerMock wiki](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent). What do I need to do in SBT to get the same result?

```
name := "my-project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // ... other dependencies above ...
    "org.powermock" % "powermock-api-mockito" % "1.5.1" % "test",
    "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-javaagent" % "1.5.1" % "test",
    "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent" % "1.5.1" % "test",
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test->default"
)
```

As shown, this project has errors:

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PowerMockRule can only be used with the system classloader but was loaded by sbt.classpath.ClasspathUtilities$$anon$1@1cee593
[error]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule.<clinit>(PowerMockRule.java:28)
[error]     ... 55 more
```

It appears SBT has its own classloader for running tests that is conflicting with what PowerMock needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using SBT 0.12.4, add the following to your `build.sbt`

```
fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test <+= managedClasspath in Test map { (cp: Classpath) =>
  val agentJar = cp.find(_.data.name.contains("powermock-module-javaagent")).get
  "-javaagent:" + agentJar.data
}
```

This causes SBT to create a new JVM process for running the tests, and adds the correct JVM command line argument to preload the javaagent module.

Comment: I'd love to see a simpler version of finding the path to the javaagent jar, such as somehow looking up the dependency directly by its ID, but scanning the classpath is the only way I could find to do it.